# How do I deal with an authorization hiccup because of bad controller naming?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller, authorization

I seem to have an authorization hiccup in my Ruby on Rails app. I have been using the following method in my application controller and it has been working beautifully.

```
def require_owner
  obj = instance_variable_get("@#{controller_name.singularize.camelize.underscore}") # LineItem becomes @line_item
  return true if current_user_is_owner?(obj)
  render_error_message("You must be the #{controller_name.singularize.camelize} owner to access this page", root_url)
  return false
end
```

I then filter in the specific controllers by:

```
before_filter :require_owner, :only => [:destroy, :update, :edit]
```

I recently created a new controller which has a bit of a different naming convention that seems to be causing a problem. Normally my controllers read `messages_controller` or `posts_controller`. In this specific case I named the resource `box_wod` which generated `box_wods_controller`.

This is the only controller that seems to be having a problem with this filter so I bet I can tell it is in the naming of it and therefore the `application_controller` method is not recognizing the owner of the record.

I am not getting an error message but the application is not letting me edit, update or destroy a record because I am not the `BoxWod owner`. My routes are correct as are my associations and the correct information is getting passed to the `box_wod` table.

Is there a way to rewrite the `application_controller` method to recognize the additional underscore in the `box_wod` resource? Or is this even my problem?

UPDATE:

Here are the three methods in the BoxWodsController:

```
  def edit
    @workout_count = Workout.count
    @box_wod = BoxWod.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @box_wod = BoxWod.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @box_wod.update_attributes(params[:box_wod])
        flash[:notice] = 'BoxWod was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@box_wod) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @box_wod.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @box_wod = BoxWod.find(params[:id])
    @box_wod.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(box_wods_url) }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: I find it hard to swallow that its the naming of the controller file that's causing you a problem.  Can you add the relevant parts of the controller in question to your question?

Answer (score 2):

In situations like this, I like to create a controller method that I can override when necessary. For example:

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController
  def require_owner
    obj = instance_variable_get("@#{resource_instance_variable_name}")
    # Do your authorization stuff
  end

  private

  def resource_instance_variable_name
    controller_name.singularize.camelize.underscore
  end
end

# box_wods_controller.rb
class BoxWodsController
  private

  def resource_instance_variable_name
    'box_wod' # Or whatever your instance variable is called
  end
end
```

Lastly, please post your `BoxWodsController` code so we can better diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the `@box_wod` instance variable is not created until the `require_owner` method is invoked so `current_user_is_owner?` is checking a nil value, resulting in it always returning false. Perhaps you need another before_filter to populate the instance variable before `require_owner` is invoked.